# What is the scope of an android permission?

Tags: android, apk, aar

I am planning on writing code for Android 8 that needs to perform Bluetooth Low Energy operations. I now my code will be used by another application. I am now researching if I should provide an apk (maybe offer a service that is callable), which in my understanding means that I have to handle all permissions myself or if I can provide an AAR library that assumes that bluetooth permissions are handled by the app using the library. As far as I understand this would be possible because manifests of libraries get merged with the manifests of application that use them. Would both of these be possible?

Comment: checkout https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html this link. It tells how manifest files get merged.

Comment: Thanks, I checked that out. I wonder now if it would make a difference if I added the bluetooth and Location Course permissions to my manifest and make the user of the library responsible for requesting them at runtime or if I would require the user of my library to even include the permissions in their manifest and leave them out of mine.